# How do I change the CSS positioning for my site to display correct across all browsers?

Tags: css

I have a site that can be seen at gronenproperties . com

I am using a div with an id "contact-add"

and absolute positioning it in the DIV where I want it to be.

Firefox shows it fine for the most part, but it shifts when i resize the window, and different browsers and OS's seem to place it somewhere else entirely.

I have been out of the game for awhile when it comes to css and making things cross compatible...In my research, it says to make the parent div relevant and should solve issue.

Pretty sure Ive done that.

If someone could teach me old tricks, but new trick to me.

Id greatly appreciate it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put everthing in a div with `margin: 0 auto;`  and `width: 960;` or `width: 1120;`